# Creating a Pass Fail Input Function

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a test form.  I have created a form with a list of steps to test.

Instead of every item on the list needing:

```
<input type="radio" name="step1">Pass<input type="radio" name="step1">Fail
```

I wanted to create a function so I could just call it every time to create it.
This is my function so far:

```
function createPassFail(name)
{
    var Pass = document.createElement('input');
    Pass.type = "radio";
    Pass.name = name;
    document.getElementById("Pass").innerHTML = "Pass";

    var Fail = document.createElement('input');
    Fail.type = "radio";
    Fail.name = name;
    document.getElementById("Fail").innerHTML = "Fail";
}
```

And then I call it with:

```
<li>Step One: Turn the TV On
<input id = "step1" onload="createPassFail(this.value)">
</li>
```

All this does is create a textbox which is not what I was going for.  I am also not sure if onload is correct.

Comment: after looking at it I'd also like to add a Comment box underneath the Pass or Fail selection, again having 1 function I could call each place I'd want to put it would be a lot easier than manually putting it in in every place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing in the `value` to the function you should pass the id:

```
onload="createPassFail(this.id)"
//                          ^^
```

I say your event should be `onblur` because I don't think `onload` is the event handler you should be using. You can use my suggestion or maybe set up a button next to the text box which, when clicked (using `onclick`) does what you want.

Moreover, you haven't inserted the pass or fail elements into HTML. Try this:

```
document.body.appendChild(Pass);
document.body.appendChild(Fail);
```

This inserts the newly-created elements directly to the end of the body element. If you would like them to be child to some element therein, you would have to access the element with a suitable method. For example, with `getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById( element ).appendChild(Pass); // do the same for Fail
```

However, this can all be easily done with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function createPassFail(name)
    {
        $('body').append('<input type="radio" id="' + name + '">Pass');
        $('body').append('<input type="radio" id="' + name + '">Fail');
    }

    $('#step1').ready(function() {
        createPassFail(this.id);
    });
});
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/DAsuJ/)

Comment: I don't need the comment box, I'd rather the Pass / Fail is up all the time.  I was trying the first way you said and couldn't get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/6yHTa/

Comment: That code should work given that the `<body>` is loaded before you do that. Also, does the jquery one work for you -- http://jsfiddle.net/DAsuJ/

Comment: I see that it works in jsfiddle but it's not working in my code.  Also would I have to add the #step1 for every step?